# make form for upload the receipt for bank transfer

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I hope you are having a great day.

I want to ask how to make a form to let customer to upload the receipts (image) of transfer the money.

thank you.
magento 1.9

Comment: Where exactly you want to upload image? Will it be done by customer or admin? It is doable.

Comment: hi @Anime, thank you for your response,
I want the customer to upload it